# JSON file not read after upload on AZURE

Tags: asp.net, json, azure

I created an asp.net API application that reads the data from a JSON file and displays it in a table. When I run it from Visual Studio it successfully reads the data and displays it but after I uploaded on Azure the table is empty.

I stored it in "jsondata" folder and the call is made like this:

```
var request = {
            method: 'get',
            url: '../jsondata/data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json"
        };
```

Head:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>


</head>
```

Body:

```html
<body>
 
    <div ng-app="myApp"
            ng-controller="myController">

           <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th>ID</th>
                       <th>Furniture Piece</th>
                       <th>Category</th>
                       <th>Price</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>

               <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="furniture in list">
                       <td>{{furniture.ID}}</td>
                       <td>{{furniture.Name}}</td>
                       <td>{{furniture.Type}}</td>
                       <td>{{furniture.Price}}</td>
                   </tr>
               </tbody>

           </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

Script for reading the JSON file with angular:

```
<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        var request = {
            method: 'get',
            url: '../jsondata/data.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json"
        };

        $scope.arrFurniture = new Array;

        $http(request)
            .success(function (jsonData) {
                $scope.arrFurniture = jsonData;
                $scope.list = $scope.arrFurniture;
            })
            .error(function () {

            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide more details so we can help

Comment: Hit F12 and read the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To serve static .json files from a Azure App Service, you need to add the following mimeMap to your `web.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Reference: [How to serve static .json files from a Windows Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/)

Comment: After a few changes here and there your solution was correct! Thank you!